# Certificado APNS Gerado Após Publicação

Tags: ios, objective-c

Gostaria de saber se caso eu gerar meu apns certificate após a publicação da app, eu tenho que publicar uma nova versão.

A app no caso já possui o código necessário para receber push notification.

Comment: Não entendi como você tem um app publicado para receber notificações sendo que não existia um certificado.

Comment: Ressucitando o tópico, apenas para ficar claro. O app possuia um certificado gerado em outra máquina por outro desenvolvedor. Este desenvolvedor desistiu do app e não passou as chaves de certificado geradas. Logo eu tinha que gerar de novo certificado para rodar na minha maquina e não sabia se isso afetaria o app em vigor visto que eu teria que gerar outra requisição de certificado e etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra tu enviar uma notificação através do APNS tu precisa além de configurar o certificado, questionar na aplicação se o usuário deseja receber notificações e caso sim ... armazenar o devicetoken no teu banco web para posteriormente com algum script (php,asp.net,etc..) utilizar o certificado e esse token para fazer uma chamada ao servers da Apple para enviar a notificação ao usuário.

Ordenando os passos:

- Gerar certificado no Provisioning Portal
- Salvar o certificado na tua maquina e converter para p12 ou pem (nos tutoriais abaixo cada um usa de um jeito)
- Enviar esse certificado e o script para envio de notificações para o teu server web que irá rodar essa rotina de notificação.
- No app tu deve configurar no appdelegate pra questionar se o usuário quer receber a notificação e caso sim salvar o devicetoken no teu banco web para usar com a rotina web.

Respondendo a tua pergunta ... a única coisa que depende se tu precisa ou não subir uma nova versão é se tu já está questionando o usuário sobre a notificação e salvando o devicetoken no teu banco. Se isso tá ok, não precisa reenviar, basta converter o certificado, salvar no teu server e criar a rotina de envio.

Abaixo 2 tutoriais, um para caso use ASP.NET e outro para PHP. 
São bem completos, descrevem desde a criação do certificado a criação do script para envio das notificações.

Asp.net - https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp

PHP - http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Boa sorte ai!

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema, a resolução simples. Apenas crie outra requisição de certificado e gere um novo certificado de push. Não será necessário republicar o app. Apenas troque o certificado no seu sistema de envio de push.